# capacity paremeter in StringBuilder(int capacity) constructor

Tags: java

Can someone please confirm what are the units of the capacity parameter in StringBuilder constructor: `public StringBuilder(int capacity)`? Is that a number of bytes or number of characters (2 * bytes)? Javadoc does not provide this detail

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that i am working with Java 6.  A lot of responses that were made do not seem to apply to the right version.

Comment: And to someone who criticised my question as "unclearn" and "not useful" - shame on you! This question was asked by me, for my specifi needs and it is for sure that the answers that nice folks provided below are useful to me and i am very greatful to all of them, and perhaps may be useful to someone else under specific circumstances. You obviously have nothing better to do with your time writing such nonsense.  If you want to do "research" - go to Java 6 API and see if the capacity parameter is well explained, then you can call me an idiot!

Comment: I wouldn't suggest that Java is not backwardly compatible unless you have strong evidence, then you can log a bug because this shouldn't happen.

Comment: Peter - never mind my mentioning of different versions. I was puzzled by others referring to a superclass I did not see in the Javadoc, but @rgettman explained clearly below what was happening, so versioning is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to javadoc

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

```
StringBuilder()
 Constructs a string builder with no characters in it and an initial capacity of 16 characters.
```

Capacity means "how many character".

Comment: thanks @user902691, i overlooked the default constructor, but this is possibly the closest answer i can get... would be nice if the documentation was more specific

Answer (score 5):

From the source of `AbstractStringBuilder`:

```
AbstractStringBuilder(int capacity) {
    value = new char[capacity];
}
```

So it's a buffer of 16-bit `char` elements.

The javadoc says, in the description at the top:

> As long as the length of the character sequence contained in the
>   string builder does not exceed the capacity, it is not necessary to
>   allocate a new internal buffer.

So the javadoc does imply what is meant by the capacity, i.e. the `length` of a character sequence, which is pretty well defined (and would be in character units) unless one gets confused about whether Unicode characters at code points `0x10000` and above count as one character or as something else.  Anyway, the source makes it clear.

Comment: thanks - see my comment below to rgettman, who offered pretty much the same reply

Answer (score 1):

`StringBuilder` extends `AbstractStringBuilder`, upon which it relies for creating the `char[]` that backs the `StringBuilder`.  It takes the `capacity` argument and directly uses it as the length of the `char[]`.  Therefore, the capacity is the number of characters, not the number of bytes.

From the source code for `AbstractStringBuilder`:

```
/**
 * Creates an AbstractStringBuilder of the specified capacity.
 */
AbstractStringBuilder(int capacity) {
    value = new char[capacity];
}
```

Here's a [link to the grepcode source code for `AbstractStringBuilder`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java#AbstractStringBuilder.%3Cinit%3E%28int%29).

Comment: Where did this come from? I fogot to say that i am using Java 6, so there is no extension of `AbstractStringBuilder` there... If that is a newest version, than it is probably backward compatible and would be the same... would you think?

Comment: This code hasn't changed since `AbstractStringBuilder` and `StringBuilder` were each created for Java 5.  `StringBuilder` has always extended `AbstractStringBuilder`, and the capacity has always been the number of `char`s.

Comment: @tulu AbstractStringBuilder says `@since 1.5`

Comment: Here is the link to Java 6 API http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/. If you navigate to StringBuilder, you will see that it extends Object and never mentions AbstractStringBuilder anywhere in description. I am starting to get suspicious we are talking about different classes?java.lang 
Class StringBuilder
java.lang.Object
  java.lang.StringBuilder

Comment: `AbstractStringBuilder` is package-private, so it doesn't show up in the Javadocs, but it's there in java.lang.

Comment: @rgettman, i did not realize that Javadoc hides some hierarchy...  this is a lesson to me...  thank you

Comment: @tulu The javadocs describe the public API, i.e. the things users can use.  How Oracle implements those classes is not supposed to be important.  So the fact that `StringBuilder` is implemented by subclassing, or not subclassing, `AbstractStringBuilder` is normally unimportant to users.  That's an implementation detail, and it could change from one release to another.  However, some of us looked at those implementation details to confirm that it worked the way we thought it would.  The `StringBuilder` javadoc does give the answer, but maybe not as clearly as it should.

Comment: @ajb, i would argue that the users of the API should not be forced to look into a source code to find a usage description of the method's arguments. It is nice that Java is an open source code, but looking at the code should not be required in such case. I appreciate that you and rgettman were doing this for me, but clearly, this is what API is for... I liked that user902691 found a hint in default constructor, this is probably what you meant by "javadoc does give the answer?" Anyway, this is not a right place perhaps to complain about Javadoc, but thanks again for your effort!

Answer (score 1):

If you notice in the javadocs a StringBuilder `is a` `CharSequence` (implements that interface). So the capacity is the number of `char` which is 16bits.